# Variable scope - recursive helper function to print all paths binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, variables, recursion, scope

I am trying to print all root to leaf paths using the following recursive DFS code:

```
def binaryTreePaths(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[str]:
    allPaths = []
    currPath = []
    def dfs(root):
        # nonlocal allPaths
        if not root:
            return False
        currPath.append(root.val)
        left = dfs(root.left)
        right = dfs(root.right)
        if not left and not right:
            allPaths.append(currPath)
        currPath.pop()
    dfs(root)
    return allPaths
```

But I am getting empty lists [[], [], [], []] as output on the following input:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Null, Null

I have tried using nonlocal statement as well to specify that I am using the allPaths variable defined in binaryTreePaths function, but am still getting the same output.

I looked at each step of dfs's execution using a debugger and allPaths does get filled, but by the end it's empty. Can someone please help me understand how the allPaths variable is being scoped here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a reference to `currPath` multiple times, when what you want is a *copy* of what `currPath` looks like at the time you call `allPaths.append`.

You also need to return `True` when `dfs` does, in fact, get an actual tree as its first argument:

```
def binaryTreePaths(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[str]:
    allPaths = []
    currPath = []
    def dfs(root):
        if not root:
            return False
        currPath.append(root.val)
        left = dfs(root.left)
        right = dfs(root.right)
        if not left and not right:
            allPaths.append(currPath[:])
        currPath.pop()
        return True
    dfs(root)
    return allPaths
```

At the cost of copying `currPath` more often, you can pass a copy as a second argument to `dfs`.

```
def binaryTreePaths(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[str]:
    allPaths = []
    def dfs(root, currPath):
        if not root:
            return False
        newPath = currPath + [root.val]
        left = dfs(root.left, newPath)
        right = dfs(root.right, newPath)
        if not left and not right:
            allPaths.append(newPath)
        return True
    dfs(root, [])
    return allPaths
```

Comment: That solved my problem.

I missed not returning True when I got a tree, thanks for that.

But I still didn't quite understand the currPath reference problem. Could you please provide a link to the documentation where I can read more about this? I am totally amazed how this is the first time I am facing this issue after coding in Python for years lol.

Comment: There is only one `list` object, referenced by `currPath`, seen by every call to `dfs`. The contents of that list change over time, but it's the *reference* to that list that gets appended to `allPaths`, and each reference sees the same list at the same point in time. You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks. I would've upvoted your answer if I had sufficient reputation lol. Thanks a ton, I was stuck on this all day today!